# How to remove an autocomplete option from notepad++

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and have enabled the autocomplete feature. For the most part I like having it, but there are a few words it tries to autocomplete that just interfere with my productivity.

For example, whenever I try to type `<?php` it will attempt to autocomplete to `<?php_egg_logo_guid`, `<?php_init_loaded_file` or a sundry of other such options. It is a bit annoying and I don't even know what the use of any of them are.

I would like to remove these unneeded options from autocomplete. Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Edit: After a few bad answers, let me clarify:
I am not trying to disable autocomplete completely, just remove a word or two from the dictionary of choices which it chooses to give hints from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the relevant **.xml** in notepad++'s program files's plugins\APIs to remove the silly php autocompletes [as explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/166940/how-do-i-edit-or-add-to-notepad-html-css-autocomplete).

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/jmc734/157ff4a4ee85f8e58102

You can add `<?php` as a suggestion. It will show as the first choice in autocomplete.

edit:

%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\php.xml

add the line:

`<KeyWord name="php" func="no"/>`

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly for me, and is even better than @cDima solution wich forec to discard some entries

Answer (score -2):

Settings > Preferences > Auto-Completion > Uncheck the Enable auto-complete & Function hint options. This should do it.